# Xcode 7/Swift 2.0 XCTestCase waitForExpectationsWithTimeout() EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, swift, asynchronous, osx-elcapitan

I have had little success practicing test driven development with asynchronous Swift 2.0 code in Xcode 7. The only solutions with which I have had any success are contrived and hacky delay mechanisms that sidestep the need for `waitForExepectationsWithTimeout()`. I would like to perform asynchronous tests as follows, but this code consistently fails:

```
import Foundation
import XCTest

class AsyncTest : XCTestCase {
    func testAsync() {
        let expectation : XCTestExpectation = self.expectationWithDescription("That waitForExpectationsWithTimeout() will actually wait.")
        let queue : dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("async", nil);
        dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in
            print("Executed!")
            XCTAssert(true, "An aphorism about success.")
            expectation.fulfill()
        })
        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(100.0, handler: nil) // Arbitrary wait period of 100
    }
}
```

Error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x6.....)

When the expectation is fulfilled (`expectation.fulfill()`) outside of the asynchronously executed closure, this test will pass as expected (so long as I comment out the fulfillment inside the closure). But doing so obviously defeats the purpose of synchronizing test evaluation.

I will note that even though the test fails, the `Executed!` message prints as one would expect. Also, if a breakpoint is introduced on the `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout...` line, the test succeeds—similarly, the test succeeds when an artificial sleep delay is introduced. This leads me to believe that `waitForExepectaionsWithTimeout()` is not waiting at all.

Admittedly I am new to Xcode and Swift, so if I am missing something obvious, I would greatly appreciate any feedback. What is wrong with my above code? Are there any environmental variables that I can provide to help debug the problem?

Running: OS X El Capitan 10.11 Beta (15A263e), Xcode 7.0 beta (7A120f)

Comment: Does the crash happen just via Xcode IDE or also when you run tests on CLI via xcodebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been having the same problem and could not figure out how to make it work. I made sure my expectations are still allocated but it still failed. So I moved to a different patter, by using a dispatch group.
See the example bellow with your code:

```swift
func testSomething(){
    let group = dispatch_group_create()
    dispatch_group_enter(group)

    let queue : dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("async", nil);
    dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in
        print("Executed!")
        XCTAssert(true, "An aphorism about success.")
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    })

    let wait_success = dispatch_group_wait(group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(2*NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    XCTAssertEqual(wait_success, 0)
}
```

I'd surely rather use the standard waitForExpectation() mechanism, but if all else fails, then this works just fine

Comment: I've tested your solution and it works, but do note that as of XCode Version 7.2 (7C68) and OS X 10.11.3 Beta (15D13b), I no longer get an error with my original code.